How should I structure my HTML email tables to make it inline-block on mobile but stacked on desktop? Typically the opposite is done
Mobile and desktop versions mockup
I have no problem getting the desktop version done, but trying to figure out how to make it go inline block on mobile has stumped me.
Not sure if I need to do a blockhide/blockshow type set up, what do you think?
My code for this content block :
    <tr>
                <td style="padding: 0px 0px 20px 0px;">
                   <table bgcolor="#ffffff" width="100%" style="border-spacing: 0; border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;" role="presentation">
 
                      <tr>
                         <td class="column-wrapper fluid-hybrid" style="padding: 0; font-size: 0; background-color: #ffffff; text-align: center; border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;">

                             <!--[if mso]>
                              <table width="100%" style="border-spacing: 0;" role="presentation">
                              <tr>
                              <td width="290" valign="middle" style="padding: 0;">
                           <![endif]-->
 
                            <table class="column column-one-half" width="100%" style="border-spacing: 0; vertical-align: middle; width: 100%; max-width: 290px; display: inline-block; color: #fff;" role="presentation">
                               <tr>
                                  <td class="padding first" style="padding: 20px;">
                                     <a href="https://example.com"><img src="https://cms.perkspot.com/media/aavjynzt/template-large-logo-image.png" width="250" alt="Image Description"></a>

                                     <h3 style="font-size: 20px; line-height: 24px;">This is under sixty characters and falls on a couple lines.</h3>
                                  </td>
                               </tr>
                            </table>
                            
                            <!--[if mso]>
                              </td>
                              <td width="290" valign="middle" style="padding: 0;">
                           <![endif]-->
 
                          
                           <table class="column column-one-half" width="100%" style="border-spacing: 0; vertical-align: middle; width: 100%; max-width: 290px; display: inline-block; color: #fff;" role="presentation">
                            <tr>
                               <td class="padding first" style="padding: 20px;">
                                  <a href="https://example.com"><img src="https://cms.perkspot.com/media/aavjynzt/template-large-logo-image.png" width="250" alt="Image Description"></a>

                                  <h3 style="font-size: 20px; line-height: 24px;">This is under sixty characters and falls on a couple lines.</h3>
                               </td>
                            </tr>
                         </table>

                              <!--[if mso]>
                              </td>
                              </tr>
                              </table>
                           <![endif]-->
 
                         </td>
                      </tr>
                     
                
 
                   </table>
                </td>

             </tr>

My CSS:
   <style type="text/css">

@font-face {
            font-family: "proxima-nova";
            src: url("https://use.typekit.net/af/efe4a5/00000000000000007735e609/30/l?primer=7cdcb44be4a7db8877ffa5c0007b8dd865b3bbc383831fe2ea177f62257a9191&fvd=n4&v=3") format("woff2"), url("https://use.typekit.net/af/efe4a5/00000000000000007735e609/30/d?primer=7cdcb44be4a7db8877ffa5c0007b8dd865b3bbc383831fe2ea177f62257a9191&fvd=n4&v=3") format("woff"),
                url("https://use.typekit.net/af/efe4a5/00000000000000007735e609/30/a?primer=7cdcb44be4a7db8877ffa5c0007b8dd865b3bbc383831fe2ea177f62257a9191&fvd=n4&v=3") format("opentype");
            font-display: auto;
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: 400;
            font-stretch: normal;
        }

      table {
         border-spacing: 0;
         border-collapse: collapse;
      }

      td {
         padding: 0;

      }

      p {
         font-size: 16px;
      }

      img {
         border: 0;
      }

      a {
         text-decoration: none;
         color: #FFFFFF;
         font-size: 14px;
      }

      .content {
         line-height: 20px;
         font-size: 16px;
      }

      u+.body .gmail-blend-screen {
         background: #000;
         mix-blend-mode: screen;
      }

      u+.body .gmail-blend-difference {
         background: #000;
         mix-blend-mode: difference;
      }

      .ExternalClass {
         width: 100%;
      }

      .ExternalClass,
      .ExternalClass p,
      .ExternalClass span,
      .ExternalClass font,
      .ExternalClass td,
      .ExternalClass div {
         line-height: 100%;
      }

      a[x-apple-data-detectors=true] {
         color: inherit !important;
         text-decoration: inherit !important;
      }
     
       .bg-color {
         background-color: #ECEBEB;

      }
     
       span.Object {
         color: inherit !important;
      }
     
      span.Object-hover {
         color: inherit !important;
         text-decoration: none !important;
      }
     
     
      @media screen and (max-width: 459.98px) {
                 .mobile-cell {
            display: inline-block !important;
            text-align: center !important;
            padding: 5px !important;

         }

         .mobile-cell img {

            width: 100% !important;
            margin: 0 auto !important;

         }

         .td-mobile-cell {

            text-align: center !important;

         }

         .mobile-text {
            width: 100% !important;
         }   

         .col-sm-12 {
                display: block !important;
                width: 100% !important;
            }

            img.co-branded {
            height: 58px !important;
            width: auto !important;
          }

      }

      @media screen and (max-width: 399.98px) {

      }

      :root {
         color-scheme: light dark;
         supported-color-schemes: light dark;
      }

      @media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {

         body,
         table {
            background: #2d2d2d !important;
            color: #ffffff !important;
         }

         .darkmode-transparent {
            background-color: transparent !important;
         }

         [data-ogsc] body,
         table {
            background: #2d2d2d !important;
            color: #ffffff !important;
         }

         [data-ogsc] .darkmode-transparent {
            background-color: transparent !important;
         }
      }
     
     
   </style>

    <style type="text/css">
      /* /\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/ CLIENT-SPECIFIC STYLES /\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/ */
      span.MsoHyperlink {
         color: inherit;
      }
   
      span.MsoHyperlinkFollowed {
         mso-style-priority: 99;
         color: inherit;
      }
   
      #outlook a {
         padding: 0;
      }
   
      /* Force Outlook to provide a "view in browser" message */
      .ReadMsgBody {
         width: 100%;
      }
   
      .ExternalClass {
         width: 100%;
      }
   
      /* Force Hotmail to display emails at full width */
      .ExternalClass,
      .ExternalClass p,
      .ExternalClass span,
      .ExternalClass font,
      .ExternalClass td,
      .ExternalClass div {
         line-height: 100%;
      }
   
      /* Force Hotmail to display normal line spacing */
      body,
      table,
      td,
      p,
      a,
      li,
      blockquote {
         -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
         -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
      }
   
      /* Prevent WebKit and Windows mobile changing default text sizes */
      table,
      td {
         mso-table-lspace: 0pt;
         mso-table-rspace: 0pt;
      }
   
      /* Remove spacing between tables in Outlook 2007 and up */
      img {
         -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
      }
   
      /* Allow smoother rendering of resized image in Internet Explorer */
   
      /* /\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/ RESET STYLES /\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/ */
      body {
         margin: 0;
         padding: 0;
      }
   
      img {
         border: 0;
         height: auto;
         line-height: 100%;
         outline: none;
         text-decoration: none;
      }
   
      table {
         border-collapse: collapse !important;
      }
   
      body,
      #bodyTable,
      .bodyCell {
         height: 100% !important;
         margin: 0;
         padding: 0;
         width: 100% !important;
      }
   
      /* /\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/ TEMPLATE STYLES /\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/ */
   
      /* ========== Page Styles ========== */
      #templateContainer {
         width: 600px;
      }
   
      body,
      #bodyTable {
         background-color: #ECEBEB;
         font-family: 'proxima-nova', Arial, sans-serif;
         font-size: 16px;
      }
   
      h1,
      h2,
      h3,
      h4 {
         color: #000;
         display: block;
         font-family: 'proxima-nova', Arial, sans-serif;
         font-style: normal;
         font-weight: bold;
         line-height: 100%;
         letter-spacing: normal;
         margin: 0;

      }
   
      h1 {
         font-size: 30px;
      }
   
      h2 {
         font-size: 26px;
      }
   
      h3 {
         font-size: 24px;
      }
   
      h4 {
         font-size: 18px;
         line-height: 22px;
         margin-bottom: 0;
      }
   
      p {
         margin-top: 0;
         margin-bottom: 0;
         font-size: 16px;
      }
   
      p.small {
         margin-top: 0;
         margin-bottom: 0;
         font-size: 14px;
      }
   
      li {
         font-size: 16px;
      }
   
      hr {
         margin: 0;
      }
   
   
   
      /* ========== Body Styles ========== */
      #templateBody {
         background-color: #FFFFFF;
      }
   
      .bodyContent {
         color: #000;
         font-family: 'proxima-nova', Arial, sans-serif;
         font-size: 14px;
         line-height: 150%;
         padding-top: 30px;
         padding-right: 20px;
         padding-bottom: 30px;
         padding-left: 20px;
         text-align: left;
         background-color: #FFFFFF;
      }
   
      .bodyContent a,
      .bodyContent a:link,
      .bodyContent a:visited,
      .bodyContent a:focus
      /* Yahoo! Mail Override */
      .bodyContent a .yshortcuts
   
      /* Yahoo! Mail Override */
         {
         color: #007bff;
         font-weight: normal;
         text-decoration: none;
         outline: none;
         border: none;
      }
   
      .bodyContent img {
         display: inline;
         height: auto;
         max-width: 560px;
      }
   
      /* ========== Footer Styles ========== */
      #templateFooter {
         background-color: #ECEBEB;
      }
   
      .footerContent {
         color: #808080;
         font-family: 'proxima-nova',Arial,sans-serif;
         font-size: 10px;
         line-height: 150%;
         padding-top: 20px;
         padding-right: 20px;
         padding-bottom: 20px;
         padding-left: 20px;
         text-align: left;
      }
   
      .footerContent a:link,
      .footerContent a:visited,
      /* Yahoo! Mail Override */
      .footerContent a .yshortcuts,
      .footerContent a span
   
      /* Yahoo! Mail Override */
         {
         color: #000000;
         font-weight: bold;
         text-decoration: none;
      }
   
      /* MY STYLES */
      .text-center {
         text-align: center;
      }
   
      .show-mobile-only {
         mso-hide: all;
         display: none;
         visibility: hidden;
         width: 0;
      }
   
      .img-full-width {
         height: auto;
         max-width: 600px;
      }
   
      .font-0 {
         font-size: 0;
      }
   
      .bg-color {
         background-color: #ECEBEB;
   
      }

      .column-header {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        float: left;
      }

            /*-- SIMPLE TWO COLUMNS LESSON --*/
      .column-wrapper {
         padding: 0;
         font-size: 0;
         text-align: center;
      }
      .column {
         border-spacing: 0;
         vertical-align: top;
         width: 100%;
         display: inline-block;
         color: #fff;
      }
      .column-one-half {
         max-width: 290px;
      }
      .padding {
         padding: 20px;
         
      }
      /*-- END SIMPLE TWO COLUMNS LESSON --*/
   
      /* /\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/ MOBILE STYLES /\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/ */
   
      @media only screen and (max-width: 599.98px) {
   
         /* /\/\/\/\/\/\/ CLIENT-SPECIFIC MOBILE STYLES /\/\/\/\/\/\/ */
         d body,
         table,
         td,
         p,
         a,
         li,
         blockquote {
            -webkit-text-size-adjust: none !important;
         }
   
         /* Prevent Webkit platforms from changing default text sizes */
         body {
            width: 100% !important;
            min-width: 100% !important;
         }
   
         /* Prevent iOS Mail from adding padding to the body */
   
         /* /\/\/\/\/\/\/ MOBILE RESET STYLES /\/\/\/\/\/\/ */
         .bodyCell {
            padding: 0px 10px !important;
            background-color: #ECEBEB !important;
         }
   
         /* /\/\/\/\/\/\/ MOBILE TEMPLATE STYLES /\/\/\/\/\/\/ */
   
         /* ======== Page Styles ======== */
         #templateContainer {
            max-width: 600px !important;
            width: 100% !important;
         }
   
         h1 {
            font-size: 24px !important;
            line-height: 100% !important;
         }
   
         h2 {
            font-size: 20px !important;
            line-height: 100% !important;
         }
   
         h4 {
            font-size: 16px !important;
            line-height: 100% !important;
         }
   
         /* ======== Header Styles ======== */
         .headerContent {
            font-size: 20px !important;
            line-height: 125% !important;
         }
   
         /* ======== Body Styles ======== */
         .bodyContent {
            font-size: 16px !important;
         }
   
         /* ======== Footer Styles ======== */
         .footerContent {
            font-size: 14px !important;
            line-height: 115% !important;
         }
   
         .footerContent a {
            display: block !important;
         }
   
         /* MY STYLES */
         .mobile-cell {
            display: inline-block !important;
            text-align: center !important;
            padding: 5px !important;
   
         }
   
         .mobile-cell img {
   
            width: 100% !important;
            margin: 0 auto !important;
   
         }
   
         .td-mobile-cell {
   
            text-align: center !important;
   
         }
   
         .mobile-text {
            width: 100% !important;
         }

         .column-wrapper.fluid-hybrid .padding.second {
            padding-top: 0 !important;
            padding-bottom: 20px !important;
         }

         td.padding.first {
            padding: 20px 20px 0px 20px !important;
         }

         .column-one-half {
            text-align: center !important;
         }

         td.padding.second h3 {
            padding-top: 20px !important;
         }

         .content-show {
                display: block !important;
                mso-hide: none !important;
            }

            .content-hide {
                display: none !important;
                mso-hide: all !important;
            }

         /* .column-wrapper {
            padding: 15px 0 !important;
         }

         .column-wrapper.fluid-hybrid .column,
         .column-wrapper.fluid-hybrid .column img {
            max-width: 100% !important;
            width: 100% !important;
         }
         .column-wrapper.fluid-hybrid {
            padding: 15px 30px !important;
         } */
      }

      @media screen and (max-width: 399.98px) {

        /* .column-wrapper.fluid-hybrid .padding.second {
            padding-top: 0 !important;
            padding-bottom: 10px !important;
         }  */

         /* .column-wrapper.fluid-hybrid {
            padding: 0 !important;
         }
         .column-wrapper.fluid-hybrid .padding {
            padding-top: 20px !important;
            padding-bottom: 0 !important;
         }
         */
      }
   </style> 

It produced this result in desktop and mobile.
Desktop
Mobile

There is a lot of code here, sorry I couldn't reproduce the perfect answer but I hope the following enables you to work it out.
I think you just want this for your media queries:

So instead of making both tables around the image and heading 100%, they should be 50%. Additionally, the table around all that should be 100%.
This is not fully 'inline-block', which uses strict widths.
Just noting that your current issue actually gives you more room on mobiles, so maybe keep that for smaller mobiles (<400px), and then do what you're trying in 400-600px range. Just a thought.

Thanks for the insight! Will try this, may have to just do a show/hide with display:none for desktop and have content show for mobile
